# changing color of a link when clicked and change back when clicked again

Tags: jquery, colors, hyperlink, navigation

I have a horizontal navigation bar at the top of my website. Two of the options have submenus which drop down when clicked and hide away when clicked again, using javascript. I wanted to make it so that each of those two options changes color when its respective submenus are revealed, and changes back they are hidden again.

HTML Structure:

```
<ul id="navigationbar">
  <li><a id="parentitem1">Option 1</a></li> 
     <nav id="dropdownmenu1">
       <ul>
         <li><a id="childitem 1a">sub-option 1a</a></li>
         <li><a id="childitem 1b">sub-option 1b</a></li>
         <li><a id="childitem 1c">sub-option 1c</a></li>
       </ul>   
     </nav>  
  <li><a id="parentitem2">Option 2</a></li>   
     <nav id="dropdownmenu2">
       <ul>
         <li><a id="childitem 2a">sub-option 2a</a></li>
         <li><a id="childitem 2b">sub-option 2b</a></li>
         <li><a id="childitem 2c">sub-option 2c</a></li>
       </ul>   
     </nav>   
</ul>
```

when the parent items are pressed, the nav section with sub items is revealed using javascript. I want to make it so that when I click a parent item to reveal its submenu, the parent item changes to gray… when you click it again to hide its submenu, it changes back to orange. I also want to make it so that when you click from one parent item to the other parent item, it will change the first parent item back to orange too.

Comment: Please post the html structure for the menu.

Comment: and show us what you've tried so far, so we know what advices to give you. *"Give someone a fish ... learn it how to fish..."* how goes that one?!...

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#super_horizontal_bla').find('.super_toggler').click(function(){

  $('.splendid').removeClass('splendid');
  $(this).toggleClass('splendid');

});
```

CSS

```
.splendid{
  super-attribute : here ;
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: thanks allot, this has got me half way there :) now i need to get it so that when I click on an option it turns the other option back to its original colour.

Comment: a better way of expressing it....  now i need to make it so that only one of the two links can be highlighted at any one time... i.e. clicking the other link will turn the first link back to its original colour and visa versa.

Comment: @JesseSutton-Jones edited my answer. Welcome to S.O btw, and if you think an answer helped you to solve your issue, make sure to accept it. And read the FAQ.